# Let $A(\theta)$ be a given function , where $\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$. Mark the correct statement below

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

> Let $  A(θ) =    \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}    \cosθ  & \sinθ  \\   
> -\sinθ  & \cosθ \\   \end{array} } \right] $ where $θ ∈ (0, 2π)$. Mark the correct statement below
>
> A. $A(θ)$ has eigenvectors in $\mathbb R^2$ for all $θ ∈ (0, 2π)$
>
> B. $A(θ)$ does not have an eigenvector in $\mathbb R^ 2$ , for any $θ
>  ∈ (0, 2π)$
>
> C. $A(θ)$ has eigenvectors in $\mathbb R^ 2$ , for exactly one value
>   of $θ ∈ (0, 2π)$
>
> D. $A(θ)$ has eigenvectors in $\mathbb R^ 2$ , for exactly 2 values of
>   $θ ∈ (0, 2π)$

A. $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, statement is false.

B. $\theta=\pi$, $A=-\mathbb I$, all the vectors in $\mathbb R$ are eigen vectors. So statement is false.

I am not able to judge (C) and (D). how to judge it? Please help me.

Comment: Try $\theta=\pi$, and see what happens. The key thing to understand is that the matrix acts as rotation by $\theta$. Also, you're misreading the question slightly. It's asking about values of $\theta$. Which values of $\theta$ are such that eigenvectors _exist_?

Comment: @quasi It has eigen value -1.Right?

Comment: Entire space is the eigen space.

Comment: Right, so the answer is . .  .?

Comment: Does there exists any other value of $\theta$ which has eigen value in $\mathbb R^2$? @quasi

Comment: Think about rotations. If you rotate a nonzero vector, can it end up being parallel  to (i.e., a scalar multiple of) what it was before the rotation?

Comment: @quasi No. Thank you very much. You mean under rotation magnitude doesn't change. Right?

Comment: Right, now you have it (+1). The key was to see the matrix as a rotation matrix, and then visualize the geometric effect rotation has on a nonzero vector.

Comment: Please note the correction. As zwim pointed out, the matrix is _clockwise_ rotation by $\theta$ (so normally it would called rotation by $-\theta$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix is clockwise rotation by $\theta$ (or equivalently, counterclockwise rotation by $-\theta$).

If you rotate a nonzero vector clockwise by an angle $\theta$, the only way the result can be parallel to the original is if $\theta$ is a multiple of $\pi$.

But it's given that $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$, so . . .

Comment: slight adjustment, it is a rotation by $-\theta$, doesn't change the interpretation of course.

Comment: Right, I was careless. Will fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is C. You can actually compute the Eigenvalues and see. But you can also think about this: by what angle can I rotate a vector so that I end up with a real multiple of the vector. It’s clear that 0, π and 2 π are the only choices, but only one of them lies in the range (0,2 π )